# Minimal IAM policy for ec2:RunInstances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to narrow down the minimal policy to run a predefined machine image. The image is based on two snapshots and I only want "m1.medium" instance types to be launched.

Based on that and with the help of [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html) and [this article](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/11/amazon-ec2-resource-level-permissions-for-runinstances.html), I worked out the following policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1385026304010",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": "m1.medium"
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-f1c3e498",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::snapshot/snap-e2f51ffa",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::snapshot/snap-18ca2000",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::key-pair/shenton",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::security-group/sg-6af56d02",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::volume/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The policy narrows down the exact image, snapshots, security group and key-pair while leaving the specific instance and volume open.

I'm using the CLI tools as follows, as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html):

```
aws ec2 run-instances --dry-run \
    --image-id ami-f1c3e498 \
    --key-name shenton \
    --security-group-ids sg-6af56d02 \
    --instance-type m1.medium
```

The `~/.aws/config` is as follows:

```
[default]
output = json
region = us-east-1
aws_access_key_id = ...
aws_secret_access_key = ...
```

The command results in a generic `You are not authorized to perform this operation` message and the encoded authorization failure message indicates that none of my statements were matched and therefore it rejects the action.

Changing to `"Resource": "*"` resolves the issue obviously, but I want to gain more understanding as to why the above doesn't work. I fully realize that this involves some degree of guess work, so I welcome any ideas.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've been contacted by Jeff Barr from Amazon Web Services and he kindly helped me find out what the issue was.

First you need to decode the authorization failure message using the following statement:

> `$ aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message 6gO3mM3p....IkgLj8ekf`

*Make sure the IAM user / role has permission for the `sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage` action.*

The response contains a `DecodedMessage` key comprising another JSON encoded body:

```
{
    "allowed": false,
    "explicitDeny": false,
    "matchedStatements": {
        "items": []
    },
    "failures": {
        "items": []
    },
    "context": {
        "principal": {
            "id": "accesskey",
            "name": "testuser",
            "arn": "arn:aws:iam::account:user/testuser"
        },
        "action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:instance/*",
        "conditions": { ... }
    }
}
```

Under `context => resource` it will show what resource it was attempting to match against the policy; as you can see, it expects an account number. The [arn documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) should therefore be read as:

> Unless otherwise specified, the region and account are required.

Adding the account number or `*` in the affected ARN's fixed the problem:

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:instance/*",
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:image/ami-f1c3e498",
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:snapshot/snap-e2f51ffa",
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:snapshot/snap-18ca2000",
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:key-pair/shenton",
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:security-group/sg-6af56d02",
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:volume/*"
]
```

Comment: The arn for AMIs does not take an account # - so it's either blank, or "*". Thank you for this post - I would have never solved this without it!

Comment: I did same as you but my , initialization failed ... don't understand . Can you please share your full policy

Comment: @Shafiulkarim That's really the whole policy I have; I guess if this doesn't answer your question, feel free to ask another one and ping me with the link.

Comment: Yes i add a new Post  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079495/aws-ec2-resource-level-initialization-failed)

Comment: I've created [a little shell function](https://gist.github.com/xiongchiamiov/b0ef0251813625307371d0e11e131759) that parses out message, unescapes it, and pretty-prints it, given just the initial encoded message.

Comment: The STS `decode-authorization-message` command helped me solve my problem, which was different from yours. Thanks for this!

Comment: At the end add: `$ aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message <message> --output text` so that is easier to format.