# AWS EC2 Resource Level , Initialization Failed

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I use this Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1385026304010",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.medium"
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:image/ami-81c603ea",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:key-pair/CodeDeploy",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:security-group/sg-5ace243d",
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:*:volume/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But it show error message , Initialization failed . I see this example in aws Documentation but dont understand why this problem happen.

#### Decoded message

```
{
  "allowed": false,
  "explicitDeny": false,
  "matchedStatements": {
    "items": []
  },
  "failures": {
    "items": []
  },
  "context": {
    "principal": {
      "id": "AIDAJXOEQNA64A677DGQO",
      "name": "DevOps1",
      "arn": "arn:aws:iam::955246940111:user/DevOps1"
    },
    "action": "ec2:RunInstances",
    "resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:955246940111:key-pair/CodeDeploy",
    "conditions": {
      "items": [
        {
          "key": "ec2:Region",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "us-east-1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The likely scenario is that the resource `"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:955246940111:key-pair/CodeDeploy"` can't be found.

Comment: In my case actually the "solution" was to remove the `Condition`. I do not know why it seems to have broken the config (got also the `key-name` error when I had a condition on the instance size in; but without the condition and all other resources the same, it works). Don't like it so much, since forcing small instances would have given a bit more security.